# search in text with mistakes by regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have the text with some mistakes e.g. `th1s ls s0me text` , and I have a set of similar chars , for example `{'1','l','i'}`, etc., which can be exchanged with each other in this text.

How can I search a value in this text by Regex ?

Is there better way than change e.g. pattern `this` to `th[i1l]s` ?

Comment: You are asking for typos and provide examples for Leet http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leet

Comment: How do you know whether the `1` is a `l` or an `i`?

Comment: I have a set of this similar char in array

Answer (score 0):

I would try

- using some dictionary for spell check(there are some downloadable) to look for similar strings if a word contains number/"strange" char. (string distance)
- create list of substitutions for numbers/"strange" chars and interate through your text char by char
- combination of both above.

I wouldnt defenetly use regex unless there are only few words to correct (for example if you know there are only 20 unique words to correct). Regex isnt among the fastest ways of text editing.